# Problems when migrating from on-premises TFS to VSO using OpsHub

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are trying to migrate from our on-premises TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online (VSO). We did it a first time just to test it out. The OpsHub application stopped a couple of times, but we finally succeeded. We did our testing and deleted the project from VSO.

The second time dident go so well. It gives the following error after migrating a lot but not all of our change sets:

> com.opshub.eai.config.exception.ConfigServiceException:
>   OH-CONFIG-0101: Exception while calling service, underlying cause :
>   could not execute query.

We can press OK and navigate into another view in the application but the same error occurs on every view. We have restarted the application, the service and even the server. We always get the same error. We decided to uninstall the application and reinstall it. That solved the problem, but it appears again after we have migrated about 60% of our source code (a day or so).

So, after 3 re installations we are about to give up. It doesn't crash on the same change set every time.

Does anyone know a way around this? Is there any way we can see the real cause of the problem and fix it?

We are using version V1.3.000B000 (latest version).

Not sure if this is the proper place to post the question, but OpsHub is referring to stack overflow for support.

Comment: Hi Olle, Can you refer the C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs folder for OpsHubTFSService.log and OpsHub.log and see what the trace of the error say?

Comment: Hi , if you are still having same failures can you share logs with us for further analysis. Kindly log a ticket in OpsHub with logs at ovsmu@opshub.com.